# how to take a picture from camera and get its name to add in database?

Tags: iphone, ios5

i want to get a photo from camera and using its name want to save in databsase...

i have used these code. i have successfully taken a picture and added in image view but now i can not able to get its name(string value)

```
ImagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            ImagePicker.delegate = self;
            ImagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            [self presentModalViewController:ImagePicker animated:YES];

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    [ImagePicker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    imageview.hidden=NO;
    imageview.image = image;

    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
    // save image in document directoties
    UIImage *image1=imageview.image;


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
    NSData *pngData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1,100.0);
    NSString *filePath;
    filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%@.jpg",dateString]]; //Add the file name
    [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file
    NSLog(@"File Path is %@",filePath);

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])  //Optionally check if folder already hasn't existed.
    {
        NSLog(@"Unable to create Folder in Documents Directory");

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess knowing the exact image name would not be an issue rather getting a unique name for the picked image would solve your purpose so that you can save the image and track it via its name. May be this can help you

```
//Fetch the Maximum id from DB
NSString* strSelect= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select MAX(id) from TableName"]; 
  NSMutableArray*  arr_test  = [[database executeQuery:strSelect]mutableCopy];

   //Check if it is the first Image or not
   if ([[[arr_test objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"MAX(id)"]isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
        img_id = 1;

    else{
        NSString *strtest = [[arr_test objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"MAX(id)"];
        img_id=[strtest intValue]+1;
    }

//Give the Image Name with Unique ID
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/image%d.jpg",img_id]];
```

Answer (score -1):

try

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)pickerr 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [pickerr dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    //Since we kept allowsEditing = YES , we use UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage else use UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"];

```
[self saveImage:image];
```

}

- (void)saveImage:(UIImage*)imagepk

{

```
Database *dbObj = [Database Connetion];

//NSLog(@"image width is %f",imagepk.size.width);



NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",appDelegate.activeId]];

[dbObj updateImage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg",appDelegate.activeId] :appDelegate.activeId];


UIImage *image = imagepk; // imageView is my image from camera
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
```

}